# Is this a conjugate prior?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

I have a parameter $\theta = (\theta_1, \theta_2)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with a multivariate normal prior $p(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\theta\mid 0, I)$. The likelihood is a univariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(y \mid \theta_1 + \theta_2, \sigma^2)$. Is the posterior a normal distribution as well?

I know in general the product of normals is not normal. But I was wondering if in this case it is. Not sure how to check it.

Comment: Did you try using Bayes?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I tried but I couldn't really solve the integral..

Comment: Also, I would suggest you clarify the model; presumably the data is iid normal, so that your likelihood is multivariate normal with mean vector whose entries are all $\theta_1+\theta_2$ and covariance matrix $\sigma^2 I$ correct?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio this is a Bayesian Inverse problem. I basically have an observational model $y = F(\theta) + \eta$ with $\eta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$ and a prior $p(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\theta\mid 0, I)$. My aim is to find the posterior $p(\theta\mid y)$. The likelihood will then be $\mathcal{N}(y \mid F(\theta), \sigma^2)$

Comment: I understand that part. But you refer to your likelihood as "univariate normal" in your question. Is your data just comprised of one data point or $n>1$ data points?

Comment: I have been told that when $F$ is a linear function and the prior is gaussian, then the posterior is Gaussian. I cannot seem to show this however. I have taken $F(\theta) = (1, 1)^\top \theta$ which is a linear function

Comment: @Golden_Ratio my bad, I didn't understand your question. I have observed a single data point $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Bayes' rule tells us

$$f(\theta|y)\propto f(y|\theta)f(\theta).$$

You have a single data point $y$ so that your likelihood is univariate (as clarified in the comments). Further assuming $\sigma^2$ is fixed, and letting $M\equiv (1,1)$ , your setup has likelihood and prior given by

$$y|\theta\sim N(M\theta,\sigma^2)\implies  f(y|\theta)\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-M\theta)'(y-M\theta)\right\}\\
\theta\sim N(0,I)\implies f(\theta)\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\theta'\theta\right\}. $$

Now try some matrix completion of the square to write the posterior as

$$f(\theta|y)\propto \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}(\theta-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(\theta-\mu)\right\}$$

for some $\mu,\Sigma^{-1}$ (dependent on $y$ of course) to show $\theta|y\sim N(\mu,\Sigma).$

Comment: I get
$$
-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}y^2 + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\theta^\top M^\top y - \frac{1}{2}\theta^\top\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}M^\top M + I\right)\theta
$$

Comment: I don't think it's possible to complete the square

Comment: @Euler_Salter Correct so far. And it is possible. Think about how you would do it if everything was scalar and extend the logic to matrices (order of multiplication matters). You can find many examples of completion of the square online. Try deriving the posterior mentioned on  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution) in the multivariate normal-normal model for practice. Also you can freely add and subtract non theta terms (since you are finding the posterior up to proportionality)

Comment: Remember you want to get the form $(\theta-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(\theta-\mu).$ What does this look like expanded?

Comment: Expanding it we get
$$
-\frac{1}{2}(\theta - \mu)^\top \Sigma^{-1}(\theta - \mu) = -\frac{1}{2}\theta^\top \Sigma^{-1}\theta + \theta^\top \Sigma^{-1} \mu -\frac{1}{2}\mu^\top\Sigma^{-1}\mu
$$

Comment: @Euler_Salter Okay now construct a $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ to match that to what you got (again, freely adding or subtracting non theta terms as needed)

Comment: Do you have any hint? I tried to guess $\Sigma^{-1} = \left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}M^\top M + I\right)$ but then it doesn't seem to work since $y$ is a scalar and if I add a term with $y(\sigma^{-2}M^\top M + I)$ then it will be a matrix